# Extend an extension point based on a JVM argument

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins, eclipse-plugin

I am using Eclipse 3.4 Plugin Development Tools. I was wondering if it is possible to conditionally extend a certain extension point based on a JVM argument?

Comment: It's entirely up to the supplier of the extension point as to when to load or deal with extensions.Are you providing the extension point or contributing an extension?

Comment: I am contributing an extension. I would like to do it programmatically based on a JVM argument at runtime though.

Comment: You can't do this for an extension in the plugin.xml. There is an `IExtensionRegistry.addContribution` method but there isn't much information about it and not all extension points expect dynamic contributions.

Comment: Are you the one who created the extension point? In such scenario you can use OSGi services instead of Extension point. which supports programmatic registration. Please refer http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/OSGiServices/article.html#osgiapiservice_overview